# Why can't the definition of convergence be alterted to this one?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

I am trying to find out of a seqence with the following property is convergent:

Let $(r_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. Suppose there is a number $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a number $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|r-r_n|>\varepsilon$ for all $n>N.$

It seems to me that this sequence is not convergent, but why?

Comment: Such a sequence may very well be convergent. Take $r_n=0$ for all $n$ and $r=1$.

Comment: You should try to find an example of a non-convergent sequence that satisfies that condition.  (Presumably this is what the problem is asking for.)

Comment: As long as $r$ is not the limit of the sequence, you can choose any sequence you want.

Comment: @voldemort That example doesn't satisfy $\varepsilon = 1$.

Comment: @flawr No, as Meelo points out below, the sequence must diverge to $\infty$ ($\infty$ here in the sense of the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$).

Answer (score 4):

You're right that such a sequence cannot be convergent. It basically says "There is some $r$ such, for any $\varepsilon>0$ that the sequence $r_n$ is only in $(r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon)$ finitely many times". Now, what this is doing is clear if you start choosing $\varepsilon$ to be really big. Like, if we chose $\varepsilon=r$, then $r_n$ could only be in $(0,2r)$ finitely many times - if we choose $\varepsilon=2r$, then we see $r_n$ can only be in $(-r,3r)$ finitely many times. Doing this, we can, for sufficiently large $n$, bound the sequence as far away from $r$ as we want. In particular, we can even prove that $|r_n|$ must go to infinity, since as we bound it in intervals like $((2-n)r,n\cdot r)$ for $n>2$ (which is where we choose $\varepsilon=(n-1)r$), it means that for all sufficiently large $n$, it must be that $|r_n|>(n-2)r$. This means $r_n$ cannot converge to any finite value.